# React UseContext causes errors

Tags: reactjs

I'm using code from a tutorial, which uses `createContext` and I'm kind of confused on what exactly it's doing, and I believe that it's causing errors where I wouldn't necessarily expect. I have two components, `Dashboard` and `Login` which are different pages of my web app. It generates the error: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` For some reason, the following line in Dashboard.js:

```
function Dashboard() {
  const [favPokemons, setFavPokemons] = useState([]);
  const { userData, setUserData } = useContext(UserContext);
  setFavPokemons(userData.user.favPokemon); // This line is the problematic line
}
```

causes an error in Login.js in its try catch clause:

```
import UserContext from "../../context/userContext";
import ErrorNotice from "../misc/ErrorNotice";

function Login () {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    const { setUserData } = useContext(UserContext);
    const history = useHistory();

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            const loginUser = {email, password};
            const loginResponse = await axios.post("https://minipokedexbackend.herokuapp.com/users/login", loginUser);
            console.log(userData); // line Login.js:21 is in image below line 22
            console.log(loginResponse) // line Login.js:22, log is in image below
            
            setUserData({
                token: loginResponse.data.token,
                user: loginResponse.data.user
            });
            localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginResponse.data.token);
            history.push("/dashboard");
        } catch(err) {
            err.response.data.msg && setError(err.response.data.msg)
        }
    };
```

Could someone explain what `createContext` and why it would be causing an error in two seemingly unrelated components? I have a feeling that it has to do with `userData` not quite being generated when `Dashboard` is rendered?

EDIT:
Sorry for the lack of information, data referenced in the Login.js file is data from my server accessing mongoDB. Its response contains token and user info, which includes their `id`, `displayname` and an array of `favpokemon`
Here's userContext.js:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export default createContext(null);
```

Here's App.js:

```
function App() {
const [ userData, setUserData] = useState({
    token: undefined,
    user: undefined
  });
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
        </Switch>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

App.js also contains some functions to check if the user is logged in.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that's the line that's causing the error? What line number is it pointing to? It says you're trying to read ".data" of a a variable that's not defined. Always start with reading the error. There are other places in the code you've shown that references a "data" key, but not on the line you show the error is coming from.

Comment: what is your initial values that you are setting to the context ? . Also since the error is about context please add your context code .

Comment: Shouldn't this `err.response.data.msg` be just `err.message`?

Comment: No, if I remove the setError line then it causes an error on start script that it expects an assignment or function call but only has an expression

Comment: What i meant was to change the line in the `catch` block to `setError(err.message);`

Comment: Sorry I see what you mean now, yes that works fine. The error still pertains though.

Comment: Are you getting the same error? If yes, then try to log `loginResponse` on the console and verify that it has a `data` property.

Comment: Yes it's the same error. It looks like loginResponse returns the proper information it should, I will paste a screen shot. But it has data and user

Comment: Stepping through in the debugger, it seems that it creates the error on history.push?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm looking at the right thing. This is what it shows under components, I will past a screen shot

Comment: Hmm, using if(userData.user){setFavPokemons(userData.user.favPokemon)} still causes the error. Unless you meant a different if-condition

Comment: Sorry, do you mean if (userData) {setFavPokemon(userData.user.favPokemon)} in Dashboard.js? Since it's not working either

Comment: userContext.js has no implementation. You are practically doing nothing there. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the info you provided in the question, I managed to create a structure of your code. There might be logic or syntax errors because of the lack of information, but I want you to have a general idea how to use Context Hook during login.

**UserContext.tsx**

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

//create the context
export const UserContext = createContext<any>(undefined);

//create the context provider, we are using useState to ensure that we get reactive values from the context

export const UserProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  //the reactive values

 const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>("");
 const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
 const [userData, setUserData] =setUserData({
            token: '',
            user: ''
        });
  
  //the store object
  let state = {
    email,
    setEmail,
    password,
    setPassword,
    userData.
    setUserData
  };

  //wrap the application in the provider with the initialized context
  return <UserContext.Provider value={state}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>;
};

export default UserContext;
```

**Login.tsx**

```
    import UserContext from "../../context/userContext";
    import ErrorNotice from "../misc/ErrorNotice";
    
    function Login () {
       
        const [error, setError] = useState();
        const { email, setEmail, password, setPassword, userData, setUserData } = useContext(UserContext);
        const history = useHistory();
    
        const submit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            try{
                const loginUser = {email, password};
                const loginResponse = await axios.post("https://minipokedexbackend.herokuapp.com/users/login", loginUser);
                console.log(userData); // line Login.js:21 is in image below line 22
                console.log(loginResponse) // line Login.js:22, log is in image below
                
                setUserData({
                    token: loginResponse.data.token,
                    user: loginResponse.data.user
                });
                localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginResponse.data.token);
                history.push("/dashboard");
            } catch(err) {
                err.response.data.msg && setError(err.response.data.msg)
            }
        };
export default Login;
```

**Dashboard.tsx**

```
import UserContext from "../../context/userContext";
import ErrorNotice from "../misc/ErrorNotice";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {

 const [favPokemons, setFavPokemons] = useState([]);
 const { userData, setUserData } = useContext(UserContext);
 
  useEffect(() => {
   setFavPokemons(userData?.user?.favPokemon);
  }, []);

}
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**App.tsx**

Here I'm using a ternary expression. If (userData.token), got to dashboard otherwise go to Login Page.

```
function App() {
 const { userData} = useContext(UserContext);
return (
 <UserProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
 {!userData?.token ? (
         <>
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Redirect exact from="/" to="/login" />
        </> 
 ) : (
<>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
<Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
<Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" />        
</> 
)
       </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for putting in the effort to write all this! Unfortunately it's not working right now but I will configure with it some more and let you know

Comment: Thank you, I fiddled around with some things and the useEffect statement in Dashboard worked!!

Comment: @matthewcy happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a habit of using null checks when you’re accessing nested values of a response.

setFavPokemons(userData.user.favPokemon);

Here, modify this line to:
setFavPokemons(userData?.user?.favPokemon);

Also, do you mind doing a console log on userData object or share the corresponding reducer to check whether the shape of the data is same or not?

Comment: Sorry was there a typo? This has syntax errors in VSCode

Comment: Ok I just added a screenshot of it. userData is the first console.log, Login.js:21

Comment: Using that line I still have the same error unfortunately

Comment: @matthewcy try changing `export default createContext(null);` to `export default createContext({});`